# Singular values calculation only with CUDA

Tags: cuda, svd, cusolver

I'm trying to use the new `cusolverDnSgesvd` routine of CUDA 7.0 for the calculation of the singular values. The full code is reported below:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <cusolverDn.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

/***********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECKING */
/***********************/
void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) { exit(code); }
   }
}
void gpuErrchk(cudaError_t ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main(){

    int M = 10;
    int N = 10;

    // --- Setting the host matrix
    float *h_A = (float *)malloc(M * N * sizeof(float));
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            h_A[j*M + i] = (i + j) * (i + j);
        }
    }

    // --- Setting the device matrix and moving the host matrix to the device
    float *d_A;         gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A,      M * N * sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, M * N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- host side SVD results space
    float *h_U = (float *)malloc(M * M * sizeof(float));
    float *h_V = (float *)malloc(N * N * sizeof(float));
    float *h_S = (float *)malloc(N *     sizeof(float));

    // --- device side SVD workspace and matrices
    int work_size = 0;

    int *devInfo;       gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&devInfo,          sizeof(int)));
    float *d_U;         gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_U,      M * M * sizeof(float)));
    float *d_V;         gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_V,      N * N * sizeof(float)));
    float *d_S;         gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_S,      N *     sizeof(float)));

    cusolverStatus_t stat;

    // --- CUDA solver initialization
    cusolverDnHandle_t solver_handle;
    cusolverDnCreate(&solver_handle);

    stat = cusolverDnSgesvd_bufferSize(solver_handle, M, N, &work_size);
    if(stat != CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS ) std::cout << "Initialization of cuSolver failed. \N";

    float *work;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&work, work_size * sizeof(float)));
    //float *rwork; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&rwork, work_size * sizeof(float)));

    // --- CUDA SVD execution
    //stat = cusolverDnSgesvd(solver_handle, 'A', 'A', M, N, d_A, M, d_S, d_U, M, d_V, N, work, work_size, NULL, devInfo);
    stat = cusolverDnSgesvd(solver_handle, 'N', 'N', M, N, d_A, M, d_S, d_U, M, d_V, N, work, work_size, NULL, devInfo);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    int devInfo_h = 0;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(&devInfo_h, devInfo, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    std::cout << "devInfo = " << devInfo_h << "\n";

    switch(stat){
        case CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS:           std::cout << "SVD computation success\n";                       break;
        case CUSOLVER_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:   std::cout << "Library cuSolver not initialized correctly\n";    break;
        case CUSOLVER_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE:     std::cout << "Invalid parameters passed\n";                     break;
        case CUSOLVER_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR:    std::cout << "Internal operation failed\n";                     break;
    }

    if (devInfo_h == 0 && stat == CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS) std::cout    << "SVD successful\n\n";

    // --- Moving the results from device to host
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_S, d_S, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) std::cout << "d_S["<<i<<"] = " << h_S[i] << std::endl;

    cusolverDnDestroy(solver_handle);

    return 0;

}
```

If I ask for the computation of the full SVD (commented line with `jobu = 'A'` and `jobvt = 'A'`) everything works fine. If I ask for the computation of the singular values only (line with `jobu = 'N'` and `jobvt = 'N'`), `cusolverDnSgesvd` returns

```
CUSOLVER_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE
```

Please note that, in this case `devInfo = 0`, so I cannot spot the invalid parameter.

Please also note that the documentation PDF lacks information about the `rwork` parameter so that I have dealt with it as a dummy parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time the cuSolver `gesvd` function only supports `jobu = 'A'` and `jobvt = 'A'`

So the error when you specify other combinations is expected.  From the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#cuds-lt-t-gt-gesvd):

> Remark 2: gesvd only supports jobu='A' and jobvt='A' and returns matrix U and VH

Comment: As of CUDA 8.0, gesvd supports jobu/jobvt = A, S, O, or N.

Answer (score 1):

**USE OF `cusolver<T>nSgesvd`**

As remarked by lebedov, as of CUDA 8.0, it is now possible to calculate the singular values only by `cusolverDnSgesvd`. I report below a slightly modified version of your code with two calls to `cusolverDnSgesvd`, one performing the singular values calculation only

```
cusolverDnSgesvd(solver_handle, 'N', 'N', M, N, d_A, M, d_S, NULL, M, NULL, N, work, work_size, NULL, devInfo)
```

and one performing the full SVD calculation

```
cusolverDnSgesvd(solver_handle, 'A', 'A', M, N, d_A, M, d_S, d_U, M, d_V, N, work, work_size, NULL, devInfo)
```

As you already remarked, the two `'A'` fields for the full SVD case are changed to `'N'` in the singular values only case. Please, note that, in the singular values only case, there is no need to store space for the singular vector matrices `U` and `V`. Indeed, a `NULL` pointer is passed.

The singular values calculation only is faster than the full SVD calculation. On a GTX 960, for a `1000x1000` matrix, the timing has been the following:

```
Singular values only: 559 ms
Full SVD: 2239 ms
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#include <cusolverDn.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "TimingGPU.cuh"

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main(){

    int M = 1000;
    int N = 1000;

    TimingGPU timerGPU;
    float     elapsedTime;

    // --- Setting the host matrix
    float *h_A = (float *)malloc(M * N * sizeof(float));
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            h_A[j*M + i] = (i + j) * (i + j);
        }
    }

    // --- Setting the device matrix and moving the host matrix to the device
    float *d_A;         gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A, M * N * sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, M * N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- host side SVD results space
    float *h_U = (float *)malloc(M * M * sizeof(float));
    float *h_V = (float *)malloc(N * N * sizeof(float));
    float *h_S = (float *)malloc(N *     sizeof(float));

    // --- device side SVD workspace and matrices
    int work_size = 0;

    int *devInfo;       gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&devInfo, sizeof(int)));
    float *d_U;         gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_U, M * M * sizeof(float)));
    float *d_V;         gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_V, N * N * sizeof(float)));
    float *d_S;         gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_S, N *     sizeof(float)));

    cusolverStatus_t stat;

    // --- CUDA solver initialization
    cusolverDnHandle_t solver_handle;
    cusolveSafeCall(cusolverDnCreate(&solver_handle));

    cusolveSafeCall(cusolverDnSgesvd_bufferSize(solver_handle, M, N, &work_size));

    float *work;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&work, work_size * sizeof(float)));

    // --- CUDA SVD execution - Singular values only
    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    cusolveSafeCall(cusolverDnSgesvd(solver_handle, 'N', 'N', M, N, d_A, M, d_S, NULL, M, NULL, N, work, work_size, NULL, devInfo));
    elapsedTime = timerGPU.GetCounter();

    int devInfo_h = 0;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(&devInfo_h, devInfo, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    if (devInfo_h == 0)
        printf("SVD successfull for the singular values calculation only\n\n");
    else if (devInfo_h < 0)
        printf("SVD unsuccessfull for the singular values calculation only. Parameter %i is wrong\n", -devInfo_h);
    else
        printf("SVD unsuccessfull for the singular values calculation only. A number of %i superdiagonals of an intermediate bidiagonal form did not converge to zero\n", devInfo_h);

    printf("Calculation of the singular values only: %f ms\n\n", elapsedTime);

    // --- Moving the results from device to host
    //gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_S, d_S, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    //for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) std::cout << "d_S[" << i << "] = " << h_S[i] << std::endl;

    // --- CUDA SVD execution - Full SVD
    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    cusolveSafeCall(cusolverDnSgesvd(solver_handle, 'A', 'A', M, N, d_A, M, d_S, d_U, M, d_V, N, work, work_size, NULL, devInfo));
    elapsedTime = timerGPU.GetCounter();

    devInfo_h = 0;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(&devInfo_h, devInfo, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    if (devInfo_h == 0)
        printf("SVD successfull for the full SVD calculation\n\n");
    else if (devInfo_h < 0)
        printf("SVD unsuccessfull for the full SVD calculation. Parameter %i is wrong\n", -devInfo_h);
    else
        printf("SVD unsuccessfull for the full SVD calculation. A number of %i superdiagonals of an intermediate bidiagonal form did not converge to zero\n", devInfo_h);

    printf("Calculation of the full SVD calculation: %f ms\n\n", elapsedTime);

    cusolveSafeCall(cusolverDnDestroy(solver_handle));

    return 0;

}
```

**EDIT - PERFORMANCE ACROSS DIFFERENT VERSIONS OF CUDA**

I have compared the performance of the singular values only calculation and the the Full SVD computations for `CUDA 8.0`, `CUDA 9.1` and `CUDA 10.0`, for a `5000x5000` matrix. Here are the results on a GTX 960.

```
Computation type               CUDA 8.0     CUDA 9.1     CUDA 10.0     
__________________________________________________________________

Singular values only           17s          15s          15s
Full SVD                       161s         159s         457s
__________________________________________________________________
```