# Use scikit-cuda to compute singular value decomposition with cuSOLVER

Tags: python, cuda, svd, pycuda, cusolver

I am trying to use scikit-cuda's wrappers for the cuSOLVER functions, in particular I want to execute cusolverDnSgesvd to compute full-matrix single precision SVD on a matrix of real numbers.

Using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107525/singular-values-calculation-only-with-cuda-7-0) and [here](https://github.com/lebedov/scikit-cuda/blob/7e7300474286019c917a6c8a4bca59405c64fbce/skcuda/linalg.py#L45) as a reference, I managed to get this far:

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import numpy as np

from skcuda import cusolver


handle = cusolver.cusolverDnCreate()

m = 50
n = 25

a = np.asarray(np.random.random((m, n)))
a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(a)

ldu = m
ldvt = n

s_gpu = gpuarray.empty(min(m, n), np.float32)
u_gpu = gpuarray.empty((ldu, m), np.float32)
vh_gpu = gpuarray.empty((n, n), np.float32)

work_size = cusolver.cusolverDnSgesvd_bufferSize(handle, m, n)

work = gpuarray.empty((m,n), np.float32)

u_gpu, s_gpu, vh_gpu = cusolver.cusolverDnSgesvd(
    handle=handle,
    jobu='A',
    jobvt='A',
    m=m,
    n=n,
    A=a,
    lda=m,
    S=s_gpu,
    U=u_gpu,
    ldu=ldu,
    VT=vh_gpu,
    ldvt=ldvt,
    Work=work,
    Lwork=work_size,
    rwork=None,
    devInfo=0
)
```

But the code isn't working, probably because I'm messing up with types.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vektor/PycharmProjects/yancut/test_svd.py", line 44, in <module>
    devInfo=0
  File "/home/vektor/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/skcuda/cusolver.py", line 577, in cusolverDnSgesvd
    int(A), lda, int(S), int(U),
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How should I provide all the arguments so that the SVD is executed in a proper way?

**UPDATE1:**
After using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780180/getrs-function-of-cusolver-over-pycuda-doesnt-work-properly) question as reference, I edited my code and I'm getting a new error.

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import numpy as np

import ctypes

from skcuda import cusolver

rows = 20
cols = 10

a = np.asarray(np.random.random((rows, cols)))
a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(a.copy())
lda = rows

u_gpu = gpuarray.empty((rows, rows), np.float32)
v_gpu = gpuarray.empty((cols, cols), np.float32)
s_gpu = gpuarray.empty(cols, np.float32)
devInfo = gpuarray.zeros(1, np.int32)

handle = cusolver.cusolverDnCreate()

worksize = cusolver.cusolverDnSgesvd_bufferSize(handle, rows, cols)
print("SIZE", worksize)

Workspace = gpuarray.empty(worksize, np.float32)

svd_status = cusolver.cusolverDnSgesvd(
    handle=handle,
    jobu='A',
    jobvt='A',
    m=rows,
    n=cols,
    A=a_gpu.ptr,
    lda=rows,
    S=s_gpu.ptr,
    U=u_gpu.ptr,
    ldu=rows,
    VT=v_gpu.ptr,
    ldvt=cols,
    Work=Workspace.ptr,
    Lwork=worksize,
    rwork=Workspace.ptr,
    devInfo=devInfo.ptr
)
status = cusolver.cusolverDnDestroy(handle)
```

And I'm getting a new error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vektor/PycharmProjects/yancut/test_svd.py", line 53, in <module>
    devInfo=devInfo.ptr
  File "/home/vektor/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/skcuda/cusolver.py", line 579, in cusolverDnSgesvd
    Lwork, int(rwork), int(devInfo))
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

It now seems that I'm doing something wrong with devInfo

Comment: *"But the code isn't working"*: what is your desired output, which are you getting instead? please edit your question

Comment: @m.s. sorry, I was distracted and forgot to add further details. Basically I'm providing the - probably - right arguments but in a wrong format, the desired output are the full matrices U,S,VT of SVD.

Comment: You haven't copied all of the error message text, it is partially cut off. Could you please edit the complete error text into the question?

Comment: @talonmies that is all the output I'm getting

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://scikit-cuda.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/skcuda/cusolver.html#cusolverDnSgesvd) it looks like each of the matrices (so `A`, `S`, `U`, `VT`) need to be passed as device pointers. So for PyCUDA gpuarrays, pass `A.ptr` rather than `A`. etc and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the directions, I was already trying something similar and my code is close to compile, I've edited my question with the new code.